# If I "swipe down to reject", will caller get a chance to leave voicemail?

Tags: lock-screens, calls, voicemail, auto-reject

A few times a year someone who isn't in my address book might call me, but every day I get several spam/scam calls. So basically anytime I see a plain number, I swipe down to make my phone stop ringing.

I've been assuming this sends the call straight to voicemail (so that if it is legit they can leave a message) but it strikes me that "rejecting" a call might hang up completely on the caller.

What happens when I "swipe down to reject" a call from the homescreen? Is there a way I can quickly ignore a call while still leaving the other party a chance to wait for it to go through to voicemail?

This is a fairly stock phone, an "Android One" Moto x4 bought from Google Fi but it does have some extra Motorola tentacles on it.

(I'm also interested in doing this automatically, but only if it uses a built-in feature and **not** some random app that *you* happen to trust, sorry.)

Answer (score 0):

Google's [Phone app Help](https://support.google.com/phoneapp/answer/2811745?hl=en) implies that I can safely reject the calls:

> To reject the call, swipe the white circle to the bottom of the screen when your phone is locked, or tap Dismiss.

followed by:

> If you’ve set up a voice mailbox, rejected callers can leave a message.

That combined with [some other research](https://callercallsback.com/tech-etiquette-the-secret-language-of-call-rejection-c322464c0395) leads me to conclude that…

- "rejecting"
- "dismissing"
- "declining"

…a call are all just different words for the same thing. And any of them will both make my phone stop ringing **and** send the caller to voicemail assuming it is available.

Whereas if my phone had a way to "silence" the call, it will make my own phone stop notifying me (ringing/vibrating) but the other caller will have to wait until it continues to ring for a while before it goes to voicemail.

Comment: If you want the phone to stop ringing, without you dismissing the call, I think you have two options: press one of the volume buttons, or enable the "Pick up to stop ringing" moto action (https://support.motorola.com/in/en/documents/MS123802/). At least on my old(er) motorola phone from 2015 both methods stop the ringing and vibration for current incoming call. The link says that the moto action switches your phone to vibrate, though.

Comment: @mnd Ah, that's a handy tip too, thanks! I always have my phone on vibrate anyway so that would be fine in my case.